# Can someone clarify Gson's unicode encoding?

Tags: java, unicode, gson

In the following minimalistic example:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class GsonStuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson("Apostrophe: '"));
        //Outputs: "Apostrophe: \u0027"
    }   
}
```

The apostrophe gets replaced by it's unicode representation in the printout. However, the String returned from the `toJson` method literally has the characters '\', 'u', '0', '0', '2', '7'.

Decoding it with json actually works and gives the string "Apostrophe: '" as opposed to "Apostrophe: \u0027". How should I decode it to get the same result?

And an additional question, why doesn't a random unicode character such as ش get encoded similarly?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

By default, gson Unicode escapes certain characters, of which `'` is one. (See `HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS` in [JsonWriter](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.java) for the complete list.)

To disable this, do

```
builder.disableHtmlEscaping();
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, just saw that JsonReader decodes such characters using `JsonReader.readEscapeCharacter()`, which actually looks fairly complicated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you can modify your code as below

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class GsonStuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson("Apostrophe: '"));
        //Outputs: "Apostrophe: \u0027"
    }   
}
```